# Javascript to set item in the sharepoint list column

Tags: javascript

I need to set item in my form (select (yes/no value)) to sharepoint list column of type (Yes/No)
Please help

Answer (score 0):

In order to set yes/no fields use the 1 for yes and 0 for no as follows:

```
 var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';
function updateListItem() {

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ListName');

this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(3);

oListItem.set_item('checkField', '1');

oListItem.update();

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

alert('Item updated!');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185011(v%3Doffice.14)